# change viewport in media query

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, viewport

I'm currently working on a responsive webdesign. The "smartphone view" is not yet ready because my client has to obtain some more budget.

Therefore I need to implement a temporary view which I want to realize with an fixed viewport that only gets activated on smartphones.

I set the viewport using on this way:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I want to change the device-width to 700 pixels if the following media query gets triggered:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px){

}
```

The following code did not work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px){
    .pagewrapper{
        width:700px;
    }

    @-ms-viewport{
        width:700px;
    }

    @-o-viewport {
        width: 700px;
    }

    @viewport {
        width: 700px;
    }

}
```

Do you know other solutions to get this done? Maybe using JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: The only way i can think of is a jquery if statement that adds a meta tag depending on media size.

Comment: try min-width rather.

Comment: @im_benton How would this statement look like?

Comment: I added the jquery I was talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my solution, which works fantastic. This way the script just runs one time and gets executed before the document is ready. Also no-js is supported. Thanks for your help.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($(window).width() < 765)
    {
        x=1;
        if(x==1)
        {
            $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=765px, initial-scale=1.0">');
            x=0;
        };
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you're using jQuery and jQuery needs to be ready. On slow connections you get a problem with that code, so you might get `'$' undefined` errors.

That's why I prefer pure JavaScript in this case:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function setViewPort() {

        if (screen.width < 640 && (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180)) {
         document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=480, initial-scale=0.68");
         //alert('480 @ 0.68, landscape');
        } else if (screen.width < 640) {
         // document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
         // disabled, since its the same as the default. if this one is different, uncomment line above
         //alert('device-width @ 1, landscape');
        } else if (screen.width >= 640) {
         document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=640; initial-scale=0.5");
         //alert('640, high res phones');
        }
    })();
</script>
```

In my case I set 480px with 0.68 zoom for portrait, 320px with 1 zoom for landscape so the ppl can see bigger text and (because this is a mobile only page) if screen.width is higher than 640 (like on my android 5" phone with 1900x1080 screen size) to 640px with 0.5 zoom (since the width always stays at 320px).

Regards, Max

Comment: How would you do this with `em` instead of `px`?

Comment: Calculation has to be done in pixels, but you may set em's then. Depending on your base size (I assume its 16px,as default in all browsers), you may divide the screen.width / base size and append +'em' to the width values.

Comment: This worked great for me! Thanks. Much prefer pure JS over jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width:700px){

}
```

You can only change your css using this type of media query. If this gets hit `min-width:700px` write your css w.r.t this. And change your container width e.g `<div class="pagewrapper"></div>`

Following *meta* tag is perfect:

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only targeting devices, I think you could try max-device-width instead of max-width or min-width.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('body').width() < 700){   
      $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=700, initial-scale=1.0">');
}
else{
      $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">');
}
```

Comment: this would cause more and more viewport tags in your html. Also no viewport for no-js.