# How do I change "initial-scale" based on portrait or landscape mode (and orientation change)?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble changing "viewport" "initial-scale" based on whether the iPhone is in portrait or landscape mode (and when the orientation changes).

I want the following in portrait mode:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
```

I want the following in landscape mode:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And I want those scales after there's an orientation change.

Here are my two unsuccessful efforts:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($(window).width() < 900)
    {
        x=1;
        if(x==1)
        {
            $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">');
            x=0;
        };
    };
</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522332

```
<script>
        if(screen.width>=1){
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">');
        } else {
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">');
        }
        $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
          if(window.orientation == 0) // Portrait 
          {
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">');
          } else // Landscape 
          {
            $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">');
          }
        });
</script>
```

[Meta Viewport just on Portrait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31165916)

I would get rid of the screen width part if I could, and just focus on whether the page is in portrait or landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.matchesMedia` along with the `orientationchange` event on the `window`.

```
const meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = "viewport";
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
   meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5";
} else {
   meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0";
}
document.head.appendChild(meta);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if(window.orientation == 0){
     meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5";
  } else {
     meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0";
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great, except when I rotate from landscape back to portrait it doesn't go back to 0.5.

Comment: Is it missing ".on("orientationchange",function(){"?

Comment: @MikeEpps If you need that, you can use the `orientationchange` event. See my updated answer.

Comment: @MikeEpps Happy to help!